# scrolling effect in react to be triggered when the page is visited from another page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have state that is updated when a link is clicked. The link is created with react-router-dom. The state holds a name of specific section on the page that is routed to. What I want is for the page to scroll automatically down to the section indicated by the state. For example if clicked on link 2, then there is a section named section 2 on the page that is routed to. Then with this value the page should scroll to section 2 automatically after loading. I tried using useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, and many other methods. Please help.

For example I tried this:

```
const [sec, setSec] = useState(null); // this is the state that is updated with clicks on another page

  useEffect(() => {


    if (sec) {
      const element = sec;
      window.location.hash = element;
      setSec(null);
    }
  }, [sec]); // this is the hook on the App.jsx
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use useLocation hook and get the hash from there. First step is to import useLocation from react-router-dom:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Inside the component function, use this:

```js
const { hash } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {

}, [hash]);
```

Hope this could help!